# R tools::texi2pdf output in different folder

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using `knitr` to produce a .tex file and then using `tools::texi2pdf` to compile it into a PDF. I get the PDF and the all the auxiliary files in the same working directory. Is there any way to change that and make the output and auxiliary files show up in a different folder?

**Code example:**

```
src = normalizePath('example.Rnw', winslash = "/")
outTex = "example.tex"
outTexFile = knit(src, output = outTex, quiet = T, envir = e)
buff = tools::texi2pdf(file = outTexFile)
```

Then all the files example.pdf, example.aux, example.log, etc... all show up in the working directory.

I could do a copy in the code, but I was wondering if there is a native way to have this.

Comment: Why not using `knitr::knit2pdf('example.Rnw')`? So you have one line of code and also your tex, pdf and auxillary files. This solves not the problem, but makes things easier.

Comment: Actually this solves my problem. Set the output = "folderout/example.tex" in knit2pdf.

Also change the options of knitr to opts_knit$set(base.dir = normalizePath("./folderout"))

see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/530 for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solves my problem. Set the output = "folderout/example.tex" in knit2pdf. Also change the options of knitr to opts_knit$set(base.dir = normalizePath("./folderout")) see github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/530 for more details